# Saving matplotlib bar plot into pdf using reportlab

Tags: python, matplotlib, reportlab

I am trying to use the code below to save a `matplotlib` plot into a pdf file using `reportlab`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
...
objects = [str(col[1]) for col in data3.columns][1:]
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = data[5][1:]
fig = plt.figure()
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5, color=['blue', 'blue',     'blue', 'yellow','yellow'], edgecolor='blue')
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('USD $Billions')
plt.title('Revenue')
fig = plt.figure()
imgdata = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png')
imgdata.seek(0)  # rewind the data
drawing = svg2rlg(imgdata)

renderPDF.draw(drawing, pdf, 10, 40)
pdf.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 94, in <module>
    renderPDF.draw(drawing, pdf, 10, 40)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py", line 29, in draw
    R.draw(renderScaledDrawing(drawing), canvas, x, y, showBoundary=showBoundary)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/reportlab/graphics/renderbase.py", line 172, in renderScaledDrawing
    renderScale = d.renderScale
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'renderScale'
```

Comment: OK, I'm late at the party but your code, or rather the intents of your code, seems to me overcomplicated. Why don't you just `plt.savefig("whatever.pdf")`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way I did it (based on a post comment I found):

```
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
def one_page_pdf(file_name, fig):
    canvas = Canvas(filename=file_name)
    img_data = BytesIO()
    figs.savefig(img_data, format="svg")
    img_data.seek(0)
    drawing = svg2rlg(img_data)
    renderPDF.draw(drawing, canvas, 10, 100)
    canvas.showPage()
    canvas.save()
```

You just provide the function with a PDF `filepath` and a `matplotlib` figure.